# SQL Server Remote Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

We have a process in which several site servers send data to a central server (through a Linked Server).  A new site has seen the job duration more than double in three weeks, and a couple of the other sites often fail due to run time overlap.

It is a two step process:

1. Insert new records
2. Update changed records

The insert only takes a few seconds, but the update takes anywhere from 5 to 20 minutes, depending on the site.  I am able to change the query that drives the update and get it down to only a couple seconds, but still when put into an `UPDATE` statement it takes several minutes.

I am leaning towards moving the jobs to a single job on the central server, so it is a pull operation which, based on the testing I have done, should be *much* faster.  However, my question is:  What is considered "best practice" in this situation?  I am going to have to change quite a bit to get this working properly, so I might as well do it right.

Comment: This sounds a bit like you're building replication - when it is in fact built into the product. Have you considered replication for your situation and ruled it out for some reason?

Comment: SQL Replication was ruled out (not by me, I was in high school) back when the system ran on SQL 7.0.  I have been wanting to investigate it (I know little about it) for other processes, but had not considered it for this one.  I imagine it would work for this, since the table structures are the same?  When looking at the central table we know where it came from based on a location fields.